# Adjusting tick length and stroke weight for scales in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I am interested in changing my scale in d3 so there are some ticks that aren't as long as others.
Similar to a ruler, I only want integers to be labeled and I want ticks representing decimals to be shortened.

Here is a mockup of the effect I am seeking done in Illustrator.
[image: a mockup of the effect I am seeking]

Here is my code so far that has allowed me to label only the integers. The tickSize tool doesn't seem to support variables.

```
var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y)
    .ticks(10)
    .tickSize(30)
    .tickFormat(function (d) {
        return d % 1 === 0 ? d + "°C" : "";
    });
```

Also, I am not sure how to make the stroke weight of the ticks thicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have created the example based on the illustration you provided. I have included all the customizable options to tailor the work according to your needs.**

```js
// Sample data
var data = d3.range(0, 10.5, 0.1); // Example data from 0 to 10 with 0.1 increments

// Set up the dimensions for the SVG container
var width = 500;
var height = 400;
var margin = { top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 20 };
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

// Define the scale
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, 10]) // Example domain
               .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom]);

// Define the axis
var yAxis = d3.axisRight(yScale)
              .tickValues(d3.range(0, 10.5, 0.5)); // Show only integer ticks

// Customize the tick marks
yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    if (d % 1 !== 0) {
        // to show decimal ticks
        //return d.toFixed(1); // Shorten decimal ticks
    } else {
        return d; // Keep integer ticks as they are
    }
});

// Append the axis to the SVG
svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - margin.right) + ",0)")
   .call(yAxis)
   .selectAll("line")
   .attr("x2", function(d) { return d % 1 !== 0 ? 5 : 10; }) // Customize tick lengths
   .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d % 1 !== 0 ? 1 : 1.5; }); // Customize tick thickness
   

svg.selectAll(".tick text")
   .attr("x",15)
   .attr("font-size",15)
   .attr("font-weight","bold")
```

```css
.axis line {
    stroke: black;
}
.axis text {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
```